# What color would humans be if our blood wasn't red?

Tags: humans, blood

Humans, currently, are varying shades of orange and brown. Sometimes paler humans are more of a reddish color. But what color would a human be if our blood was blue, green, or any other non-red color? Would we still be orange-ish? Would we just be a different shade of the blood color? Or a mix of the blood color and orange?

Comment: Our color would depend more on the visual spectrum our eyes can perceive than on our blood. Species with broad color perception are colorful, and those without (most mammals are colorblind) are drab. Exceptions for camouflage, but that's the general rule. I concur with @PcMan we'd look about the same - tan with pigment. That's what human tissue drained of blood looks like, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Mostly the same.

Blushes, sunburn and infections might look a lot different.

Usually skin tone is determined by *the skin*'s coloration, not the underlying blood.  The “yellowness” of skin is due to carotenoid anti-oxidants, a result of how much fruits and vegetables one eats. The "brownness" of the skin comes from Melanin in the deeper layers of the skin, either from adaptation to sun (suntan) or from genetics.

Consider when one removed/reduces the skin's contribution to color. A very white person (little skin melanin coloration) that has been stuck indoors for a long time.

Their skin is WHITE, with a vaguely translucent look, and BLUE veins. There is almost no evidence that the underlying blood is red. (and *NO*, the blood in those veins is not blue. It is quite red. That's an effect of light scattering through the cells of the skin)
[image]

A bit, a tiny bit, of the underlying color comes directly from the blood color, but this is usually only visible if the skin is flushed, or damaged.

The few places where the skin is very thin with blood near the surface (like lips), or where the blood-containing tissues are covered by colorless nonliving material (like nails) will show the blood color of course.